# What is a good strategy for transferring a complete object over an MVC Web API?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

We would like to separate our DAL and Model layers from the rest of the world by making the Model objects accessible through a Web API. Since the model is not merely a DTO, serialization is the only solution that comes to mind. Is this a good pattern? Are there better ways of exposing the Model objects to remote clients?

Comment: are you exposing the API as an exact match against the model, or is there a business case to automap merges of various individual models to create the desired result?? the reason being, some hierarchies may cause you issues due to circular references unless you are able to flatten them out and/or remove parent relationships (or flag those attibutes as non serialisable)

Comment: I'm talking Domain Models, not directly mapped data models. One model will be constructed from several domain models and the logic that allows them to interact with each other and expose a good interface for a View Model or other type of client.

Comment: ok, it's all becoming clear now.. one resource that I found last year was on the codeproject. this presented a pretty basic cleaned up solution *template* that demoed this almost exactly as you are now describing. let me see if I can figure the article (it was 9 months or so ago)

Comment: this is lingering in my tmp bookmarks: http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/07/03/Building-Out-a-Clean-REST-ful-WebApi-Service-with-a-Minimal-WebApi-Project.aspx might be helpful, may be a white elephant.. :-) also, https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/WebApi.Hal

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Web API, consumers have to deserialize the content they receive from the Web API. Little bit of more work but depend on the requirement. For a remote client, I think this would be good light weight clean solution but limited only for HTTP request methods.

If the main requirement is separating domain model, there is another pattern called **[Model View ViewModel (MVVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)**, where you can separate your Domain Model (DM) from the View Model (VM).

All your schema stays in the DM and VM does the customer validations, error messages etc. Also there is a good tool called **[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)** which can be used for mapping your DM model classes to VM model classes if there are differences between them.

Comment: in the absence of the OP's clarity on the use case, I too would opt for the Automapper route, rather than exposing the model objects directly. this gives additional benefit in being able to present a normalised version of the certain data to be consumned by 3rd parties

Comment: I am very old friends with AutoMapper, and we plan on using MVVM, with a copy of the model being received over the web API, instead of just instantiating and populating it.

Comment: ok, i understand better now. i thought you were exposing it as a 3rd party API, rather than a decoupled layer in your app ;)

Comment: Are you doing a `DM > VM > Web API > Consumers` ?

Comment: DB > DMa > Web API > DMb > VM > Consumers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Serialization is the way. What is most common is to just do a Json(object) in asp.net MVC to serialize to object to Json and then deserialize it on the client.

Also, when you do a Http Put or Http Post on an MVC API, the Json object is automatically deserialized & mapped to the object that is part of the parameter.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult PutMemoboard(int id, Memoboard m)
```

In the above case when you do an api/putmemoboard/123 and post Memoboard data in Json format, it is automatically bound.

Similarly, you would just use Json(memoboard) to serialize inside a HttpGet action.

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult GetMemoboard(int id)
  {
    Memoboard memoboard = repository.GetMemoboard(id);
    return Json(memoboard, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```